# Hide gridview button when status id not equal to 1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a function to load `gridview1` and i want to view grid view button coloumns that are at coloumn 7 and 8 only when `M_Status` from query is equal to 1 , their are multiple records against `m_id=2` having `m_status` equal to 2 , 1, 3 but i want to show approve and deny buttons only against `m_id` =1

```
   private void loadvisitor()
    {

        con1 = new SqlConnection(constring1);
        string seelctquery = "SELECT  M_Status,d.MD_ID , d.MD_Visitor_Name,d.MD_Visitor_Cell, d.MD_Visitor_Company,s.M_StatusName,  p.purpose_name ,  m.M_DateTime FROM  Vms_Meeting M left outer join  Vms_MeetingD  d  on m.M_ID= d.M_ID  left outer join  Vms_Purpose p  on  m.Purpose_ID= p.purpose_id inner join vms_MeetingStatus as s on d.M_Status = s.M_Status WHERE m.M_ID=2 order by m.M_ID desc;";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(seelctquery, con1);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(seelctquery, con1);

        if (con1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {

            con1.Open();
        }


        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {


                string stid = (string)dr["M_Status"];
                if (stid == "1")
                {


                }


            }
        }


        con1.Close();
    }
```